# JavaScript Security - Access to the DOM by an outsider

Tags: javascript, security, dom

A quick question about security in JavaScript. I am currently writing a small application that aids a user in manipulating XML Documents. The application is a JS script that is loaded with the page, and the User uploads a file that the script processes.

I was wondering how open this system is to people outside of the local machine gaining access to the DOM as it is displayed on a Users screen. The only communications with a server are the initial downloading of a script at page load and the sending of a string to be processed by the server. I am not concerned with the sending of the string part, only how easy it would be to gain access to the information that a User is currently working with as displayed on the screen and any data found in the DOM.

Thanks for any help in advance! Please let me know if the question is unclear at all!

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

- you are not including any 3rd party content within the page
- are using an SSL encrypted connection to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks/content injection
- the user is actually paying attention to the SSL certificate (look up SSL proxies/connection termination and renegotiation by a trusted man in the middle)
- the user's computer is clean (i.e. no malware, malicious browser addons etc.)

it should be as secure as it can be. If any of the above points are not true, the system cannot be fully trusted anymore. If any 3rd party script/content/program is introduced anywhere at these points, it's not really possible to guarantee an unobserved communication.

Comment: thanks deceze! Do you know of any literature on the subject you could recommend?

Comment: Not really. I'd peruse http://security.stackexchange.com though for more details and maybe more targeted questions.